# Sending a double message for action to occur

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm currently designing a system for my GCSE coursework. For the coursework, I am making a bollard system, controlled by the internet / traffic lights.

I've been experimenting with an Arduino Uno and Ethernet shield, in order to fulfill the control by the internet.

When I telnet into my Arduino, and send it the command "S#UP", the red LED comes on, and stays on for 30 seconds. If I send the command again, the Arduino does not turn on the LED, unless the command was send twice, consecutively. Also, if I were to send a different command, for example "S#DOWN", the LED does not even turn on, no matter how many times I send it.

Does anyone have any ideas for my? Anything I've blatantly missed or got myself confused on?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
String authcode, newstatus, command;  
bool UP, DOWN, EMERGANCY;
long UPTime, DOWNTime, EMERGANCYTime, LastFlash;
bool NextFlash;

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

EthernetServer server(1265);

char serverHost[] = "LambdaLaptop";
EthernetClient phpClient;



int R = 8;
int G = 9;

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("=----------------------=");
  Serial.println("=- Traffic Management -=");
  Serial.println("=-    System Loaded   -=");
  Serial.println("=----------------------=");

  Serial.println("");

  authcode = String("4b4fec50eaa13b98934c36863293b5cf");
  LastFlash = millis();
  NextFlash = HIGH;

  pinMode(R, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (client.available() > 0) {
      char thisChar = client.read();
      command += thisChar;
      ProcessCMD( command );
    }else{
     if(command.length() > 0 ){
       command = String("");
     }
    }
  }
  if( UP ){
    if( UPTime > millis() ){
      digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
    }else{
      UP = false;
      digitalWrite(G, LOW);
    }
  }else if( DOWN ){
    if( DOWNTime > millis() ){
      digitalWrite(R, HIGH);
    }else{
      DOWN = false;
      digitalWrite(R, LOW);
    }
  }else if( EMERGANCY ){
   if( EMERGANCYTime > millis() ){
     if( LastFlash + 100 < millis() ){
       digitalWrite(R, NextFlash);
       if(NextFlash == LOW){
         NextFlash = HIGH;
       }else{
         NextFlash = LOW;
       }
     }
    }else{
      EMERGANCY = false;
      NextFlash = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(R, LOW);
    }
  }  
}

void ProcessCMD( String CMD ){
  if(CMD == "S#UP"){
    UP = true;   
    UPTime = millis() + 30000;
    if(CMD.length() > 11){
      command = String("");
    }
  }else if(CMD == "S#DOWN"){
    // Make the thing go DOWN.
    // GREEN LIGHT
    DOWN = true;
    DOWNTime = millis() + 30000;
    if(CMD.length() > 11){
      command = String("");
    }
  }else if(CMD == "S#EMERGANCY"){
    // Make the thing go DOWN.
    // Flash RED beacon.
    EMERGANCY = true;
    EMERGANCYTime = millis() + 15000;
    if(CMD.length() > 11){
      command = String("");
    }
  }else if(CMD == "TEST"){
    UP = true;
  }else if(CMD == "TEST2"){
    UPTime = millis() + 30000;
  }else{
    if(CMD.length() > 11){
      command = String("");
    }
  }
}

void SetStatus( String newstatus ){
  if (phpClient.connect(IPAddress(192,168,1,10), 80)) {
    phpClient.println(String("GET /setstatus.php?authcode=") + authcode + String("&status=") + newstatus + String(" HTTP/1.1"));
    phpClient.println("Host: LambdaLaptop");
    phpClient.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    phpClient.println("Connection: close");
    phpClient.println();
    phpClient.stop();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Couldn't connect to the system!");
    phpClient.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Two things: don't use String it is very inefficient and messy. Secondly, you have misspelled "emergency".

Comment: Another problem is with your times.  Not only should they be `unsigned long` (or better, `uint32_t`), but your method of dealing with elapsed time will fail at millis() rollover.

Comment: A third issue: your whole method of building up (and clearing, and indeed everything about) your command string is flawed.  What's so special about the magical number 11...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be far better to use char arrays instead of the String class (perhaps 11 bytes, if that is the largest command?).

eg.

const int MAX_COMMAND = 11;

char command [MAX_COMMAND];

---

```
 if (client.available() > 0) {
      char thisChar = client.read();
      command += thisChar;
      ProcessCMD( command );
```

You appear to be processing the command for every received byte. This means you will process "S", "S#", "S#D", "S#DO" etc. You need to wait until the whole command has arrived.

Then, once the command has been processed, empty out the command ready for next time.

---

```
void ProcessCMD( String CMD ){
```

Also all upper-case is usually reserved for constants, not variables like CMD.

---

Finally, your detection of end-time by addition will fail when millis() wraps. This might not matter in a small test, but you may as well teach the right way. Instead of adding an interval, remember the start time and detect when the interval is up, eg. instead of:

```
if( UPTime > millis() ){
```

You would write:

```
if (millis () - UPTime >= 30000) {
```

Where UPTime is now the *start* of the interval (that is, you remember when the interval starts, and do the above subtraction to find the end of it).

---

### References

- [Processing incoming serial data](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial) - the same techniques apply to Ethernet
- [millis() overflow ... a bad thing?](http://www.gammon.com.au/millis) - how to handle millis() wrap-around
- [State machines](http://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine) - managing events happening on the fly

Answer (score 0):

I do not have and ethernet shield at this moment to test on it your code but hopefully the next observations will help to solve your issue.

> If I send the command again, the Arduino does not turn on the LED,
>   unless the command was send twice, consecutively.

It seems that your string is not correctly processed, probably caused by "garbage" from previous received string or incomplete string. I think is from this part of the code

```
 if (client.available() > 0) {
  char thisChar = client.read();
  command += thisChar;
  ProcessCMD( command );
```

You are trying to append a char (one byte) to your command string; by doing this you are not getting the received string necessarily because the "+=" is for retrieve char by char (for example, inside a while loop). First try to print thisChar variable to ensure what are you getting and also you can print client.available() to see how many bytes you got.

Second, for your `ProcessCMD` function it could be better to use pointers to handle the `command` variable, meanwhile you must clean `command` variable always (and not only when `CMD.lenght > 11` ), i.e,

```
if(CMD.length() > 11){
  command = String("");
}
```

must be at the end of the ProcessCMD function

```
  command = String("");
```

Also you can ensure that when you set `UP=true`, also set `DOWN=false` and so on. I prefer the Switch-Case structure to handle commands.

Try to follow arduino examples to better understand.

Cheers.